# How to resolve 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' in phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email using my gmail account but i am getting an error

> "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host".

I have tried port 587,465 25 but still its not working.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $message=
        'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
        Subject:    '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
        Phone:  '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
        Email:  '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
        Comments:   '.$_POST['comments'].'
       ';
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

// Instantiate Class
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set up SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
$mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

$mail->Encoding = '7bit';

// Authentication
$mail->Username   = "rhlsngh302@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
$mail->Password   = "*********"; // Your Gmail password

// Compose
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

// Send To
$mail->AddAddress("rhlsngh302@gmail.com", "RahulName"); // Where to send it - Recipient
$result = $mail->Send();        // Send!
$message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
unset($mail);

}
?>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name"    />
                  <br />
                  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                  <br />
                  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                  <br />
                  <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
                  <br />
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
                  <br />
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                </fieldset>
        </form>
        <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
    </div>              
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` Add that to your code. You should get an error called. Given the above though, I'm almost positive this is an issue with the openssl extension not being enabled.

Comment: I m getting this error

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, while initiating PHPMailer send in the parameter  `true` like,

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
```

This will help you to catch and handle exceptions.

Secondly, try this

```
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // instead of tls
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$PHPMailer->SMTPOptions = array (
    'ssl' => array (
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

works for me!

Comment: I think it is not the case since according to the documentation it is for errors with certificates in SSL connections, and not with total lack of response from the server like described in the error provided by the user.

Answer (score 2):

TLS on port 465 will not work - that port expects SSL. You should change it to port 587. You should not change to ssl for encryption as it's been deprecated since 1998.

It would also help if you [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and base your code on an [up-to-date example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).